# Excel countifs and backslashes

Tags: excel, countif

How would one could backslashes in a range?

I'm using...

```
=COUNTIFS('Attendance Data'!8:8,"/",'Attendance Data'!$2:$2,">"&D7)
+COUNTIFS('Attendance Data'!8:8,"\",'Attendance Data'!$2:$2,">"&D7)
```

Forward slashes are counting fine but backslashes are omitted.

Thanx for reading,
Sam

EDIT: Images

[image: Output]

E7 conaints this formula...

```
=COUNTIFS('Attendance Data'!8:8,"/",'Attendance Data'!$2:$2,">"&D7)
+COUNTIFS('Attendance Data'!8:8,"\",'Attendance Data'!$2:$2,">"&D7)
```

Then I have another Sheet called Attendance Data with 8:8 conainting /, \, M, O, U, I, G and C's.

This is an actual snippet of the data...

[image: Snippet]

https://a.uguu.se/48YEhmto7Bwk_example.xlsx

EDIT:
Count's backslashes fine using COUNTIF on a separate sheet

```
=COUNTIF($AE4:$ZZ4,"\")
```

Comment: I have no problem counting backslashes with COUNTIFS... maybe a sample screenshot would help? In other words, we need a [reprex].

Comment: Attachment is amended after OP

Comment: What does your formula return?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Returns nothing. Counts the forward slashes fine. and in another sheet counts backslashes fine.

Comment: Try `+COUNTIFS('Attendance Data'!8:8,"*\*",'Attendance Data'!$2:$2,">"&D7)`

Comment: No go, unfortunately. If I change the character to something else it counts fine, just backslashes for some reason. Thanx for helping.